# bash excecuting each line of file and checking for sucess

Tags: bash

I had a file with variable number of lines, and each line is a command, say, `file1.txt`:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

My intention is to execute each line, and report "good" if the command is sucess.
Else report "bad" the command failed.

I tried like below:

```
while read line

do
$i
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                then
                "echo good"
        fi
                "echo bad"
done< file1.txt
```

But this was not working. I know I am doing some silly issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are reading `$line` and then using `$i`. Also, `echo "bad"` is not in the `else` block, but in the normal one. So it will be always printed.

You may also need to use `eval`:

```
while read line
do
   eval "$line"
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "good"
   else
       echo "bad"
   fi

done < file1.txt
```

Also note it is important to quote the variables as in `eval "$line"`.